# Is it possible to use parallel processing in aws lambda function?

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multiprocessing

I want to process some code in parallel, I used `threading.Thread` and also `multiprocessing.Process` but weirdly they both took more time then normal execution which is the opposite of what i want.

The code works well on other systems, but on lambda function it does not works as expected.

I also tried this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/

But didn't get any performance upgrade.

Can anyone tell me if its possible over lambda and if yes how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you don't have to do anything special.

The reason you saw degraded performance is because your lambda function was most likely too small.

AWS measures CPU performance in vCPUs, where [1 vCPU is a virtualized thread on a CPU core](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html).

With AWS lambda, the only thing you can scale vertically is memory, but CPU scales with it. To be precise, [every 1,769MB of RAM corresponds to 1 vCPU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console).

Increase the vCPU count by increasing the RAM and you will see proportionally increased parallel processing performance.

Comment: Thanks! yes indeed. but i have a question, when i first time, set 7+ GB from 1+ GB it showed 2 processors, but afterwards when i set 5+ GB it showed 4 processors. Is there a reason for it? When the next time function will run, is it sure that there will be 4 processors?

Comment: What do you mean by "it showed 4 processors"? Sounds like this is a separate question about how Python detects different AWS vCPU configurations.

Comment: Sorry, i programmatically checked the number of processors for the lambda function and it showed `2 processors at 7+ GB` but when i checked again it showed `4 processors for 5+ GB` . I got number of processors using this command `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: This is a different question, separate from your original one. You shouldn't rely on that information, rely on the AWS documentation I linked.